# Move file from Google Storage Bucket to Google Drive using Java while running on the Google App Engine Flex

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I am running an application on the Google App Engine Flex environment.  My goal is to allow file uploads from the application to a Google Drive.  Since the App Engine does not have a file system (or one that I really understand), Google's documentation says to upload to a Storage Bucket:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-storage

I have that code working great - uploading to the Storage Bucket.  The Google Drive code is also working great.

My question is - how do I get the Storage Bucket file up to the Google Drive?

I found a few posts, which suggest that I have to download the file from the Storage Bucket, which, from my understanding, would have to be saved to a file system and then picked up by the Google Drive code to upload to the Google Drive.

[copy file from Google Drive to Google Cloud Storage within Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48122091/copy-file-from-google-drive-to-google-cloud-storage-within-google)

[How to download a file from Google Cloud Storage with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141998/how-to-download-a-file-from-google-cloud-storage-with-java)

All I need to do is to set a `java.io.File` object from the Storage Bucket download.  I have the `blob.getMediaLink()` returned from the Google Storage code - is it possible to use that instead of downloading?

Google Storage code:

```
public static String sendFileToBucket(InputStream fileStream, String fileName) throws IOException {
    Logger.info("GoogleStorage: sendFileToBucket: Starting...");

    GoogleCredential credential = null;
    String credentialsFileName = "";
    Storage storage = null;
    Blob blob = null;
    List<Acl> acls = null;

    // credential = authorize();

    // storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    try {
        Logger.info("GoogleStorage: sendFileToBucket: Getting credentialsFileName path...");
        credentialsFileName = Configuration.root().getString("google.storage.credentials.file");
        Logger.info("GoogleStorage: sendFileToBucket: credentialsFileName = " + credentialsFileName);

        Logger.info("GoogleStorage: sendFileToBucket: Setting InputStream...");
        InputStream in = GoogleStorage.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(credentialsFileName);
        if (in == null) {
            Logger.info("GoogleStorage: sendFileToBucket: InputStream is null");
        }
        Logger.info("GoogleStorage: sendFileToBucket: InputStream set...");

        try {
            storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(in)).build()
                    .getService();
        } catch (StorageException se) {
            System.out.println("--- START ERROR WITH SETTING STORAGE OBJECT ---");
            se.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("--- END ERROR WITH SETTING STORAGE OBJECT ---");
        }

        // Modify access list to allow all users with link to read file
        acls = new ArrayList<>();
        acls.add(Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER));

        try {
            Logger.info("GoogleStorage: sendFileToBucket: Setting Blob object...");
            blob = storage.create(BlobInfo.newBuilder(BUCKET_NAME, fileName).setAcl(acls).build(), fileStream);
            Logger.info("GoogleStorage: sendFileToBucket: Blob Object set...");
        } catch (StorageException se) {
            System.out.println("--- START ERROR WITH SETTING BLOB OBJECT ---");
            se.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("--- END ERROR WITH SETTING BLOB OBJECT ---");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("--- START ERROR SENDFILETOBUCKET ---");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("--- END ERROR SENDFILETOBUCKET ---");
    }
    Logger.info("GoogleStorage: sendFileToBucket: blob.getMediaLink() = " + blob.getMediaLink());
    return blob.getMediaLink();
}
```

Google Drive code:

```
public static String uploadFile(java.io.File file, String folderIDToFind) throws IOException {
    String fileID = "";
    String fileName = "";
    try {
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Starting File Upload...");
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        Drive service = getDriveService();
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Completed Drive Service...");

        // Set the folder...
        String folderID = Configuration.root().getString("google.drive.folderid");
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Folder ID = " + folderID);

        String folderIDToUse = getSubfolderID(service, folderID, folderIDToFind);

        String fullFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Full File Path: " + fullFilePath);
        File fileMetadata = new File();

        // Let's see what slashes exist to get the correct file name...
        if (fullFilePath.contains("/")) {
            fileName = StringControl.rightBack(fullFilePath, "/");
        } else {
            fileName = StringControl.rightBack(fullFilePath, "\\");
        }
        String fileContentType = getContentType(fileName);
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: File Content Type: " + fileContentType);
        fileMetadata.setName(fileName);
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: File Name = " + fileName);

        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Setting the folder...");
        fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderIDToUse));
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Folder set...");

        // Team Drive settings...
        fileMetadata.set("supportsTeamDrives", true);

        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(fileContentType, file);

        File fileToUpload = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent).setSupportsTeamDrives(true)
                .setFields("id, parents").execute();

        fileID = fileToUpload.getId();
        Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: File ID: " + fileID);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    Logger.info("GoogleDrive: uploadFile: Ending File Upload...");
    return fileID;
}
```

In the post above, I see how to get the Storage Bucket file - but how to do I get that over to the `java.io.file` object:

[How to download a file from Google Cloud Storage with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141998/how-to-download-a-file-from-google-cloud-storage-with-java/44205060#44205060)

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With many thanks to @Ying Li, I finally have a solution.  I ended up creating a temp `java.io.File` using the `blob.getMediaLink()` URL that is returned once you upload to a Storage bucket.  Here is the method I created:

```
public static java.io.File createFileFromURL(String fileURL, String fileName) throws IOException {

    java.io.File tempFile = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(fileURL);
        Logger.info("GoogleControl: createFileFromURL: url = " + url);
        Logger.info("GoogleControl: createFileFromURL: fileName = " + fileName);
        String filePrefix = StringControl.left(fileName, ".") + "_";
        String fileExt = "." + StringControl.rightBack(fileName, ".");
        Logger.info("GoogleControl: createFileFromURL: filePrefix = " + filePrefix);
        Logger.info("GoogleControl: createFileFromURL: fileExt = " + fileExt);

        tempFile = java.io.File.createTempFile(filePrefix, fileExt);

        tempFile.deleteOnExit();
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, tempFile);
        Logger.info("GoogleControl: createFileFromURL: tempFile name = " + tempFile.getName());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return tempFile;
}
```

So, the full class looks like this:

```
package google;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.*;
import com.google.cloud.storage.*;

import controllers.GlobalUtilities.StringControl;
import play.Configuration;
import play.Logger;

/**
 * @author Dan Zeller
 *
 */

public class GoogleControl {

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "PTP";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;
    private static final String BUCKET_NAME = Configuration.root().getString("google.storage.bucket.name");
    public static final String FILE_PREFIX = "stream2file";
    public static final String FILE_SUFFIX = ".tmp";

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static GoogleCredential authorize() throws IOException {
        GoogleCredential credential = null;
        String credentialsFileName = "";
        try {
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: authorize: Starting...");

            Logger.info("GoogleControl: authorize: Getting credentialsFileName path...");
            credentialsFileName = Configuration.root().getString("google.drive.credentials.file");
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: authorize: credentialsFileName = " + credentialsFileName);

            Logger.info("GoogleControl: authorize: Setting InputStream...");
            InputStream in = GoogleControl.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(credentialsFileName);
            if (in == null) {
                Logger.info("GoogleControl: authorize: InputStream is null");
            }
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: authorize: InputStream set...");

            Logger.info("GoogleControl: authorize: Setting credential...");
            credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(in, HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY)
                    .createScoped(Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            System.out.println("Could not find file " + credentialsFileName);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Logger.info("GoogleControl: authorize: Ending...");
        return credential;
    }

    public static java.io.File createFileFromURL(String fileURL, String fileName) throws IOException {

        java.io.File tempFile = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(fileURL);
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: createFileFromURL: url = " + url);
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: createFileFromURL: fileName = " + fileName);
            String filePrefix = StringControl.left(fileName, ".") + "_";
            String fileExt = "." + StringControl.rightBack(fileName, ".");
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: createFileFromURL: filePrefix = " + filePrefix);
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: createFileFromURL: fileExt = " + fileExt);

            tempFile = java.io.File.createTempFile(filePrefix, fileExt);

            tempFile.deleteOnExit();
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, tempFile);
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: createFileFromURL: tempFile name = " + tempFile.getName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return tempFile;
    }

    public static void downloadFile(String fileID) {
        // Set the drive service...
        Drive service = null;
        try {
            service = getDriveService();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            service.files().get(fileID).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String getContentType(String filePath) throws Exception {
        String type = "";
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
            type = Files.probeContentType(path);
            System.out.println(type);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return type;
    }

    public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
        Logger.info("GoogleControl: getDriveService: Starting...");
        GoogleCredential credential = null;
        Drive GoogleControl = null;
        try {
            credential = authorize();
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: getDriveService: Credentials set...");
            try {
                GoogleControl = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return GoogleControl;
    }

    public static String getPath() {
        String s = GoogleControl.class.getName();
        int i = s.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (i > -1)
            s = s.substring(i + 1);
        s = s + ".class";
        System.out.println("Class Name: " + s);
        Object testPath = GoogleControl.class.getResource(s);
        System.out.println("Current Path: " + testPath);
        return "";
    }

    public static String getSubfolderID(Drive service, String parentFolderID, String folderKeyToGet) {
        // We need to see if the folder exists based on the ID...
        String folderID = "";
        Boolean foundFolder = false;
        FileList result = null;
        File newFolder = null;

        // Set the drive query...
        String driveQuery = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '" + parentFolderID
                + "' in parents and name='" + folderKeyToGet + "' and trashed=false";

        try {
            result = service.files().list().setQ(driveQuery).setIncludeTeamDriveItems(true).setSupportsTeamDrives(true)
                    .execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (File folder : result.getFiles()) {
            System.out.printf("Found folder: %s (%s)\n", folder.getName(), folder.getId());
            foundFolder = true;
            folderID = folder.getId();
        }
        if (foundFolder != true) {
            // Need to create the folder...
            File fileMetadata = new File();
            fileMetadata.setName(folderKeyToGet);
            fileMetadata.setTeamDriveId(parentFolderID);
            fileMetadata.set("supportsTeamDrives", true);
            fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");
            fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(parentFolderID));

            try {
                newFolder = service.files().create(fileMetadata).setSupportsTeamDrives(true).setFields("id, parents")
                        .execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Send back the folder ID...
            folderID = newFolder.getId();
            System.out.println("Folder ID: " + newFolder.getId());
        }

        return folderID;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static java.io.File sendFileToBucket(InputStream fileStream, String fileName) throws Exception {
        Logger.info("GoogleControl: sendFileToBucket: Starting...");

        GoogleCredential credential = null;
        String credentialsFileName = "";
        String outputFileName = "";
        Storage storage = null;
        Blob blob = null;
        List<Acl> acls = null;
        java.io.File returnFile = null;

        try {
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: sendFileToBucket: Getting credentialsFileName path...");
            credentialsFileName = Configuration.root().getString("google.storage.credentials.file");
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: sendFileToBucket: credentialsFileName = " + credentialsFileName);

            Logger.info("GoogleControl: sendFileToBucket: Setting InputStream...");
            InputStream in = GoogleControl.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(credentialsFileName);
            if (in == null) {
                Logger.info("GoogleControl: sendFileToBucket: InputStream is null");
            }
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: sendFileToBucket: InputStream set...");

            try {
                storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(in)).build()
                        .getService();
            } catch (Exception se) {
                System.out.println("--- START ERROR WITH SETTING STORAGE OBJECT ---");
                se.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("--- END ERROR WITH SETTING STORAGE OBJECT ---");
            }

            // Modify access list to allow all users with link to read file
            acls = new ArrayList<>();
            acls.add(Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER));

            try {
                Logger.info("GoogleControl: sendFileToBucket: Setting Blob object...");
                blob = storage.create(BlobInfo.newBuilder(BUCKET_NAME, fileName).setAcl(acls).build(), fileStream);
                Logger.info("GoogleControl: sendFileToBucket: Blob Object set...");
            } catch (Exception se) {
                System.out.println("--- START ERROR WITH SETTING BLOB OBJECT ---");
                se.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("--- END ERROR WITH SETTING BLOB OBJECT ---");
            }

            Logger.info("GoogleControl: sendFileToBucket: blob.getMediaLink() = " + blob.getMediaLink());

            // Let's build a java.io.file to send back...
            returnFile = createFileFromURL(blob.getMediaLink(), fileName);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("--- START ERROR SENDFILETOBUCKET ---");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("--- END ERROR SENDFILETOBUCKET ---");
        }
        return returnFile;
        // return outputFileName;
    }

    public static String uploadFile(java.io.File file, String folderIDToFind) throws IOException {
        String fileID = "";
        String fileName = "";
        try {
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: uploadFile: Starting File Upload...");
            // Build a new authorized API client service.
            Drive service = getDriveService();
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: uploadFile: Completed Drive Service...");

            // Set the folder...
            String folderID = Configuration.root().getString("google.drive.folderid");
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: uploadFile: Folder ID = " + folderID);

            String folderIDToUse = getSubfolderID(service, folderID, folderIDToFind);

            String fullFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: uploadFile: Full File Path: " + fullFilePath);
            File fileMetadata = new File();

            // Let's see what slashes exist to get the correct file name...
            if (fullFilePath.contains("/")) {
                fileName = StringControl.rightBack(fullFilePath, "/");
            } else {
                fileName = StringControl.rightBack(fullFilePath, "\\");
            }
            String fileContentType = getContentType(fileName);
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: uploadFile: File Content Type: " + fileContentType);
            fileMetadata.setName(fileName);
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: uploadFile: File Name = " + fileName);

            Logger.info("GoogleControl: uploadFile: Setting the folder...");
            fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderIDToUse));
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: uploadFile: Folder set...");

            // Team Drive settings...
            fileMetadata.set("supportsTeamDrives", true);

            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(fileContentType, file);

            File fileToUpload = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent).setSupportsTeamDrives(true)
                    .setFields("id, parents").execute();

            fileID = fileToUpload.getId();
            Logger.info("GoogleControl: uploadFile: File ID: " + fileID);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Logger.info("GoogleControl: uploadFile: Ending File Upload...");
        return fileID;
    }

}
```

Here is the code snippet that starts it all off:

```
try {
    Logger.info("AdultPTPController: Starting File Upload...");
    File file = null;
    File fileFinal = null;
    String fileName = "";
    String fileContentType = "";
    String filePath = "";
    String fileID = "";
    String bucketFilePath = "";
    String bucketFileName = "";
    // String folderIDToFind =
    // adultDemo.getNew_Provider_Id().toString();
    String folderIDToFind = adultDemo.getLegacy_Provider_Id().toString();
    Http.MultipartFormData<File> formData = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    if (formData != null) {
        Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<File> filePart = formData.getFile("fileAttach");
        if (filePart != null) {
            fileName = filePart.getFilename().trim();
            // Is there a file?
            if (!fileName.equals("") && fileName != null) {
                Logger.info("AdultPTPController: File Name = " + fileName);
                fileContentType = filePart.getContentType();
                file = filePart.getFile();
                long size = Files.size(file.toPath());
                String fullFilePath = file.getPath();
                InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(fullFilePath);
                // Send the file/multipart content to the storage
                // bucket...
                Logger.info("AdultPTPController: Sending file to GoogleStorage - sendFileToBucket");
                File bucketFile = GoogleControl.sendFileToBucket(fileStream, fileName);
                //File bucketFile = null;
                Logger.info("AdultPTPController: File Sent to GoogleStorage - sendFileToBucket");

                // Send the file to Google Drive...
                if (bucketFile != null) {
                    // Upload the file and return the file ID...                            
                    Logger.info("AdultPTPController: File is not null, sending to uploadFile...");
                    bucketFileName = bucketFile.getName();
                    Logger.info("AdultPTPController: bucketFileName = " + bucketFileName);
                    fileID = GoogleControl.uploadFile(bucketFile, folderIDToFind);
                    Logger.info("AdultPTPController: File ID = " + fileID);
                    if (!fileID.equals("")) {
                        // Success...
                        // Create a file record...
                        FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
                        // Create a unique ID...
                        fileUpload.setFileKey(fileUpload.createFileKey());
                        // Set the needed fields...
                        fileUpload.setRecordID(adultDemo.getLegacy_Provider_Id().toString());
                        fileUpload.setRecordKey(adultPTP.getPtpkey());
                        fileUpload.setCreatedBy(user.getFullname());
                        fileUpload.setCreatedByEmail(user.getEmail());
                        fileUpload.setCreatedByKey(user.getUserkey());
                        fileUpload.setCreatedDate(GlobalUtilities.getCurrentLocalDateTime());
                        fileUpload.setDateCreatedDisplay(
                                GlobalUtilities.getStringDate(fileUpload.getCreatedDate()));
                        // Set the file info...
                        fileUpload.setFileID(fileID);
                        fileUpload.setFileName(fileName);
                        fileUpload.setFilePath(filePath);
                        String folderID = Configuration.root().getString("google.drive.folderid");
                        fileUpload.setFolderID(folderID);
                        // Set the URL...
                        String urlString = Configuration.root().getString("server.hostname");
                        String fullURL = urlString + "/downloadfile?ptpKey=" + adultPTP.getPtpkey() + "&fileID="
                                + fileID;
                        fileUpload.setFileURL(fullURL);
                        fileUpload.save();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I hope this helps the next guy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the file to your local machine from GCS (Google Cloud Storage) and then have your Java code pick it up and send to Google Drive.

The second part of your code can be used. But your first part is actually uploading a file to GCS and then obtaining a serving URL. I don't think you want that.

Instead look into [downloading from GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-object-download), and then ran the second part of your code and upload that file to Google Drive.

===

If you are using App Engine and doesn't want to use a local machine to perform the uploading, you can try the following:

[Read from GCS and get the file to outputStream in the HTTP response](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage). You can then [upload the file to Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads). There's a bit of code to add, you need to make sure the byte stream you get is converted to a java.io.File.

Comment: When you say Local Machine, do you mean my actual machine or the App Engine where the application is running?  I was hoping to have the process on the App Engine, where the file is saved to the bucket, then downloaded in the App Engine instance, picked up by the Google Drive code and sent to the Google Drive.  Also, the link above, do you have an example of how to integrate into my code above?  Thanks

Comment: I meant your actual local machine. You can't download to GAE (Google App Engine), we don't let you keep data on the instance (and even if you did, it would be lost when the instances reboots).

Comment: It seems that when running a web application on the App Engine and you want to let the users upload a file to a Google Drive folder, it seems that it can't be done.  Based on the Google documentation, Stack Overflow posts, and ideas listed here, you will have to save to a bucket, download to the users machine, then upload to the Google Drive.  That seems ridiculous - why can't we get the file from the user's local machine and upload to the Google Drive?  I see no answers or samples for this, since Google states the file needs to be saved to the bucket first. I appreciate the help - thanks.

Comment: Have you tried my updated answer? Saving to the bucket is fine, but I think you can hack around the "download to local machine" part. While you can't download to a GAE instance, you can skip that entire part.

Read from GCS, get the file in byteStream format in the HTTP response, then put that in a java.io.File and upload that to Google Drive. In theory it should work. Keep in mind that this is not a general standard use case, so it's untested.

Comment: Thanks for the direction - I found a solution and posted as the answer.