# Issue getting Firebase Image url using java -maven code [Not android]

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have been working on utility where I have written java maven and in which I want to upload the file to the firebase and get the firebase URL for image.

Right Now I am using gsutil: Google cloud storage SDK using below code

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance()
         .getService();
 Bucket bucket = storage.get(bucketName);

 //... code required

return "gs://" + blobId.getBucket() + "/" + blobId.getName();
```

But above code is giving me gsutil URL which is not usable in HTML img src.

I want firebase URL which can be used in HTML img tag.

In shor I want download URL using Java-Spring code(not android).

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Admin SDK provides a fairly thin wrapper around the Google Cloud Storage SDK for Java. In Node.js this is accomplished by calling `getSignedUrl()`, but it seems on Java that you need `getMediaLink()` as shown in the [Cloud Storage documentation](https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/using-cloud-storage).

Also see:

- [How to download a file from Google Cloud Storage with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141998/how-to-download-a-file-from-google-cloud-storage-with-java)

Comment: getMediaLink() is giving me null.